# I receive pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted when launching Filebeat and other Beats

Tags: filebeat, sigabrt

I have this error launching any Beat. I'm using Debian 12 and OSS Beats (Filebeat, Metricbeat, .. version 7.12.1 but also same problem with 7.13.1).
I configured previously pf_ring for Suricata, I really don`t know if this problem with Beats is related to any system change of performance configuration.
I was trying several times, and few time ago I managed to run Filebeat. It seems most of the times it fails but not always...

```
2023-09-14T16:17:32.355-0500    INFO    instance/beat.go:468    metricbeat start running.
2023-09-14T16:17:32.357-0500    INFO    filesystem/filesystem.go:57 Ignoring filesystem types: sysfs, tmpfs, bdev, proc, cgroup, cgroup2, cpuset, devtmpfs, debugfs, tracefs, securityfs, sockfs, bpf, pipefs, ramfs, hugetlbfs, devpts, mqueue, pstore, autofs, efivarfs, configfs, fuse, fusectl, binfmt_misc
2023-09-14T16:17:32.357-0500    INFO    [system.fsstat] fsstat/fsstat.go:57 Ignoring filesystem types: %ssysfs, tmpfs, bdev, proc, cgroup, cgroup2, cpuset, devtmpfs, debugfs, tracefs, securityfs, sockfs, bpf, pipefs, ramfs, hugetlbfs, devpts, mqueue, pstore, autofs, efivarfs, configfs, fuse, fusectl, binfmt_misc
2023-09-14T16:17:32.358-0500    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:164   Config reloader started
runtime/cgo: pthread_create failed: Operation not permitted
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f839ff97d3c m=5 sigcode=18446744073709551610

goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime: unknown pc 0x7f839ff97d3c
stack: frame={sp:0x7f836b7fd900, fp:0x0} stack=[0x7f836affe268,0x7f836b7fde68)
00007f836b7fd800:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000 
00007f836b7fd810:  0000000000000000  00007f836b7fdae8 
00007f836b7fd820:  00000000014fffb5 <runtime.gentraceback+4501>  00007f836b7fda90 
00007f836b7fd830:  00007f836b7fdb80  0000000001512d01 <runtime.return0+1> 
00007f836b7fd840:  00007f836b7fd908  0000000000000000 
00007f836b7fd850:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000
```

results of ulimit -a:

```
ulimit -a
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 95881
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 3074064
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 1024
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) 95881
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if more info or logs are needed to debug

I tried to reboot, to unload pf_ring module, to stop Suricata process... I expect a normal behaviour of Beats

SOLUTION:

glibc >= 2.35 added a new rseq syscall that is not in our default list of allowed syscalls. That is likely the problem you are running into.

```
seccomp:
 default_action: allow
 syscalls:
 - action: allow
   names:
   - rseq
```